# Moving CSS from Web to Local breaks it

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC/ASP.NET. Up to this point, I have been working with a JQuery CSS file on the web. I have now decided that I want to point to a local copy, so I downloaded it to an appropriate folder and updated the link address.

Now however, it looks like some of the CSS isn't loading. Firebug shows the CSS file in the list of loaded style sheets, so it isn't a bad link... I feel it may be some MVC facet I have failed to learn yet. Ideas?

Code (top of a partial view):

```
@*<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">*@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.widgets.css">
```

Before and After
[Pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYqOK.jpg)

Comment: Your style sheets are probably being cached.

Comment: I think you should remove `//` from the beggining of the link.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes That is the old code, now commented out, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Mark I moved the link to the Layout.cshtml file so it could be in the true header of the web page, no dice. I also cleared my browser cache to be sure, still no dice. This doesn't seem to be it either.

Comment: @Chris, just curious, do the dropdowns work other than being styled different? Having just looked at your screenshots, it looks more like the JS library has been left out.

Comment: @Mark No change was made in JS whatsoever, and it still works fine. The element in question is a JQuery ComboBox which is consuming an HTML Select tag with MVC generated options (from SQL Data). https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Do you have this directory: "images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png" Looks like you are missing reference to this icon.

Comment: @Mark Yes! That absolutely fixed it. Feel free to throw up the solution, I don't want to deny you your kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the following image/directory: **"images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png"**

Be sure to check for exterior URL links when localizing CSS sheets.